# Use multiple pagination in the same page in Joomla?

Tags: joomla1.5

i am creating one component with two list with each paging ,but when clicked one pagination the other also shows pagination with limits, So how can can i create for each for pagination

[image: Here the image for paing which i have in this problem for same page of pagination]

Answer (score 0):

There is a patch that you need to apply :

In  [there are patch for Joomla!1.5](http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=18323&usg=AFQjCNEGyGROztz80q4qMyds_rmdG-lssQ)

In  [there are patch for Joomla!1.6](http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=18458&usg=AFQjCNHVPHsoyRIMqirWpd5A6egq8_Gheg)

I tested it and it works perfectly .

Good luck